# How To Get Remote Ubuntu GUI in local Virtualbox Ubuntu System?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, gnome

The goal: a GUI interface to remote Ubuntu servers at Digital Ocean and AWS.

Status: Running Ubuntu Desktop in Virtualbox in a Windows 10 host. Have ssh connection to the server with the `ssh -X -C` comand. From a terminal window in the server, individual graphical applications open on the local graphical desktop: pgAdminIII, gedit, etc. Entering `gnome-session` causes about a 30 second delay until a prompt is displayed. A graphical interface doesn't come up.

Question: How to get a complete gnome desktop on the server in a window on the local Virtualbox hosted Ubuntu?

Thanks,

David

Comment: have you tried x11 forwarding? if not - check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589844/set-up-x11-forwarding-over-ssh

Comment: Yes...that is working. `xclock`, `gedit`, etc. all come up locally from the remote server without a problem. 

However gnome doesn't. Not sure why. Googling for quite a while gave no answers. Most posts on the topic are about basic x11 forwarding.

I have the ssh tunnel and remotes working, but why won't gnome come up?

Comment: quite a lot of opengl based programs only able to work in so called "direct glx" mode ( when region of a video memory is initially allocated by DRI2 extension and later gl driver talks to video hardware directly, bypassing X11 networking ). Try to disable composite manager etc