# X11Forwarding working in debug mode, but not in normal

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to set up X11Forwarding, I've followed this thread : [set-up X11 Forwarding over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589844/set-up-x11-forwarding-over-ssh)

But it's not working ($DISPLAY is empty)... However, if I launch another instance in debug mode on another port, as mentionned in an answer it works... What could the problem be ?

(NOTE : I already tried to reload and restart sshd)

Comment: Is x11 forwarding enabled in sshd.conf

Comment: well... I just said I followed the thread linked, and that I can connect to a sshd running debug mode and execute X11 app from it, so of course I did

Comment: The person who asked the other question described exactly how he was testing, what error messages he got, and what was logged by the ssh server. You've provided none of that information. Please take another look at the other question, and add some useful information to _your_ question instead of making everyone ask for it.

Comment: I can't since it works well in debug mode. it's only when running normally it that it doesn't work

Comment: At least the error from the x application you try to launch would be helpful

Comment: I forgot to mention that $DISPLAY is not set

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your link and also saw the instruction to start with the debug mode. Questions:

- Does it also work when you start an  additional ssh instance without the -d flag? This would indicate that your current instance has taken its configuration from elsewhere.
- Does it work when connecting with -Y (as instructed next to the debug mode proposal) instead of -X (as instructed in the referenced question of that thread)
- You are also suggested to connect with the -v (verbose) flag set. This would be very helpful to help you out.